# Questions that may... flickers when you change your title

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

There is a problem I have every time I want to post a new question on SO. The "Questions that may already have your answer" section is good but when you edit your title it's resizes multiple time. It's very annoying.

A solution is to fix its height, clear its content and show a loader icon.